# JSONObject returns null in Firebase

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Data is successfully being added to Firebase (confirmed through firebase console). But when I am trying to extract the Data I am getting NULL values.

```
package com.example.shaur.nimblenavigationdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class all_books extends Fragment {

    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = db.getReference();
    DatabaseReference bookRef = rootRef.child("BookAds");


    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    List<Books_getter_function> bookList;

    String b_name,b_price,b_desc,negotiate,contact,email;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_books, container, false);


        bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        final BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(getActivity(),bookList);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_books);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

//This hardcoded data is being displayed correctly.
        //bookList.add(new Books_getter_function("Ghatak 2008","200","test@gmail.com","Excellent book must buy","1233214390",R.drawable.book_blue_icon));  

        bookRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                //LOG IS WORKING FINE
                Log.i("Book",value);

                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(value);
                    b_name = object.getString("BookName");
                    b_price = object.getString("BookPrice");
                    contact = object.getString("ContactNumber");
                    b_desc  = object.getString("Description");
                    negotiate = object.getString("Negotiable");
                    email = object.getString("Email");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                bookList.add(new Books_getter_function(b_name,b_price,email,b_desc,contact,R.drawable.book_blue_icon));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        return view;
    }
}
```

LOG value is correct : {UserId=IVXm0BS3NWZnsp7e6qz0W3bsYz2, BookPrice=122, Description=excellent, ContactNumber=9899999999, Negotiable=true, BookName=HK das, Email=test@gmail.com}

The value PASSED by JSONObject to String b_name,b_price is null. Why is this happening? 
I have LOGGED the value string and it is giving me correct output now I just have to extract data.

I have verified everything else is correct added hardcoded data to check whether is gets displayed and it work completely fine.

The DataExtracted from FireBase by JSONObject is the Problem here.

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: In the try catch Block, the Data passed to String is null, I can't figure out why? While the String value variable has correct data in it.

Comment: Most probably because your `value` string is not in proper JSON format? Shouldn't JSON be in `{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firebase the database is made of JSON, but you dont need to use `JSONObject` to get the data. You can simply do this, instead of:-

```
 b_name = object.getString("BookName");
                b_price = object.getString("BookPrice");
                contact = object.getString("ContactNumber");
                b_desc  = object.getString("Description");
                negotiate = object.getString("Negotiable");
                email = object.getString("Email");
```

do this:

```
String b_name=dataSnapshot.child("BookName").getValue().toString();
String b_price=dataSnapshot.child("BookPrice").getValue().toString();
String contact=dataSnapshot.child("ContactNumber").getValue().toString();
String b_desc=dataSnapshot.child("Description").getValue().toString();
String negotiate=dataSnapshot.child("Negotiable").getValue().toString();
String email=dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue().toString();
```

the `child()` is an attribute in your database

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: @shauryauppal Glad I could help! happy coding